# Is there a way to make if statement shorter and better looking when checking for multiple similar conditions? (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement

(not sure if title explains the matter well enough)

I have this piece of code:

```
string input = "5";
   if (input == ""  ||
       input == "1" ||
       input == "2" ||
       input == "3" ||
       input == "4" ||
       input == "_" ||
       input == "6" ||
       input == "7" ||
       input == "8")
     {/* ... */}
   else
     {/* ... */}
```

How can I make it look better? Is there some way to remove repeating `input`s?

**upd**: switch will probably make it even worse, because in my case I'm going to check for many conditions, most of which will run very limited number of methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can write an extension method like this one:

```
    public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] list)
    {
        return list.Contains(value);
    }
```

And use it as follows:

```
if (input.In("", "1", "2", ...))
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use a `switch` in the general case (although that experience is much better in VB.NET) but if they're all going to be one character or less, you can use a string:

```
if("1234_678".Contains(input)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the conditional expression in a function and code becomes easier to read. The actual expression isn't any simpler but the code is a bit easier to read.

```
if (IsSomething(input))
{
 /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using a switch. Its probably more presentable. This would be more appropriate for individual tests if that is what you want.

More information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
    switch(input){
      case "1":
      // Do something
      break;
      case "2":
      // Do something else
      break;
      case "_":
      // Do something else
      break;
      default:
      // Otherwise do this
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

            if (list.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("found");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be an option to solve this problem:

```
  string input = "5";
  List<string> Values = new List<string>{ "1", "2","3","4", "5" };
  if(Values .Contains(input))
    {
         //Your Action
    }
```

Comment: you don't need new string[] in your values definition

Comment: Also you don't have to enclose values using (), this will cause a compile time error